# ¿ Como Limpiar Foco de un QLabeEdit en PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt

Bueno tengo un problema que trata sobre el resaltado|foco de un `QLabelEdit`
intento quitar el foco ya que cunado seleciono otro QLineEdit este sige con Puntero de texto
( | ) que te indica que  se puede escribir intente usar

```
self.LeUsuario.focusOutEvent=self.des_foco
def des_foco():
    self.QLineEdit.ClearFocus()
```

Pero el foco sigue selecionado
ahora cuando uso el selecionador de foco :

```
self.QLineEdit.focusIntEvent=self.foco
def foco():
    pass
```

El indicador de texto (|) o cursor de texto No aparece
Pero si se puede escribir, creo estas funciones de foco para resalar otro label cuando este QLineEdit este selecionado 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Qué obtienes al ejecutar `print(app.style().metaObject().className())`

Comment: Este era el problema .. que no retornaba un valor a la funcion super() por que lo intente desde el main principal y tenia que crear una rama solo para el QlineEdit con el (protome to) retornar al terminar el foco  `return super().focusInEvent(e)`

Comment: QWindowsVistaStyle eso imprime