# PyQt5 Como llamo a un objeto de la clase principal que esta dentro de una clase personalisada?

Tags: python, pyqt5

La clase personalisada puede llamar a un objeto de la clase principal en este caso 
el `QLineEdit`, Intento hacer esto por que cada vez que haga un foco a un `QLineEdit` resaltara o pintar un texto tipo `QLabel`

```
from PyQt5 import uic,QtWidgets,QtCore,QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
class QlineEDIT(QLineEdit):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        super(QlineEDIT, self).__init__(parent)
    def focusInEvent(self, e ):
        self.setStyleSheet("border-color: red;")
        return super().focusInEvent(e)
    def focusOutEvent(self, a0):
        self.setStyleSheet('''border:0.5px solid;
                            color: rgb(199, 209, 217);
                            border-color: rgb(156, 156, 156);
                            padding:3px;''')
        return super().focusOutEvent(a0)
```

Intente poner estos métodos en la función principal pero esto me genero otro error ya que no retorna a el valor de el objeto al terminar la función o eso es lo que creo [Este es el otro problema](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/342917/como-limpiar-foco-de-un-qlabeedit-en-pyqt5)

Comment: Hola Edwin, a ver si lo he entendido, tienes una clase principal (`QMainWindow` por ejemplo) con instancias de `QLabel` y `QLineEdit`  (composición) y quieres que cuando un `QLineEdit` determinado gane el foco un `QLabel` se resalte?

Comment: Exactamente eso necesito

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay varias formas de conseguir lo que buscas, como usar `EventFilter`. No obstante, una muy simple es aprovechar tu clase derivada de `QLineEdit` para que directamente pasar al inicializador una referencia al label asociado de forma que pueda modificarse también su estilo cuando el `QLabel` gana o pierde el foco:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QLabel, QLineEdit


class MyQLineEdit(QLineEdit):
    def __init__(self, *args, attached_label=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.attached_label = attached_label

    def focusInEvent(self, e):
        self.setStyleSheet("border-color: red;")
        if self.attached_label is not None:
            self.attached_label.on_attached_ledit_focus_in()
        return super().focusInEvent(e)

    def focusOutEvent(self, e):
        self.setStyleSheet('''border:0.5px solid;
                            color: rgb(199, 209, 217);
                            border-color: rgb(156, 156, 156);
                            padding:3px;''')
        if self.attached_label is not None:
            self.attached_label.on_attached_ledit_focus_out()
        return super().focusOutEvent(e)


class MyQLabel(QLabel):
    def on_attached_ledit_focus_in(self):
        self.setStyleSheet('''color: rgb(127, 0, 255);
                            background-color: rgb(19, 209, 217);
                            padding:3px;
                            ''')

    def on_attached_ledit_focus_out(self):
        self.setStyleSheet('''
                            color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
                            background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
                            padding:3px;
                            ''')


class TestApp(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        label_1 = MyQLabel(self, text="Dato 1")
        label_1.move(70, 50)
        edit_1 = MyQLineEdit(self, attached_label=label_1)
        edit_1.move(120, 50)

        label_2 = MyQLabel(self, text="Dato 2")
        label_2.move(70, 100)
        edit_2 = MyQLineEdit(self, attached_label=label_2)
        edit_2.move(120, 100)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = TestApp()
    main.resize(300, 200)
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Estoy usando `QtDesigner` perdon por no mencionarlo antes
Mi clase `MyQLineEdit` esta usando una funcion de QDesigner Promoción(Promote to) para el QLineEDIT y al momento de instanciar la clase `MyQLineEdit  >> edit_1 = MyQLineEdit(self, attached_label=label_1)` esta importa el archivo de funciones en este caso MyQLineEdit en ese archivo como resolveria.

Comment: Para realizar fuera de la clase con Qtdesigner solo modifique el argumento de la clase MyQLineEdit | desde la clase principal `self.LePassword.attached_label=self.intUsuario`
espero que a alguien mas le sirva